# Can't use MediaPlayer.create in new View.OnFocusChangeListener() in Android app

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

OK, I'm having an issue that I don't understand in my Android app. In the code below, I'm getting an error on the `MediaPlayer mpWeight = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mppig)`;

Holding my cursor over create says:

The method `create(Context, int)` in the type `MediaPlayer` is not applicable for the arguments (`new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){}, int`)

What does that mean, and more importantly, how do I resolve it?

Here's the whole routine:

```
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.weight);
    tv.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){
      @Override
      public void onFocusChange(View v,boolean hasFocus){
            /* When focus is lost check that the text field
             * has valid values.
             */
            if (!hasFocus) {
                float tempweight = Float.parseFloat(et_weight.getText().toString());
                if(tempweight > 200){
                    MediaPlayer mpWeight = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mppig);
                    mpWeight.start();
                }
            }
      }          
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this` in your `MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mppig);` corresponds to the instance of `OnFocusChangeListener` but you need to pass the application context.

Change your create call to

`MediaPlayer.Create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.mppig);`